# ¿Como obtener la clave de mysql al crear instancia en AWS Lightsail?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, aws, amazon-rds

actualmente cree un instancia en aws Lightsail tipo lamp, todo me va bien, quiero saber donde esta ubicada la contraseña para conectarme a la base de datos que trae por defecto, aunque tengo pensado conectar esta instancia con una vpc de mysql rsd, para tener la capa de aplicación separada de la de negocio(la app en Linghsail y la base de datos rds mysql) soy novato en esto cualquier tip lo agradezco, saludos

Comment: la passwd esta en en la carpeta bitnami_application_password 
ejecutar comando: cat bitnami_application_password

Comment: Hola, Daniel. Bienvenido.. :-)  Te respondiste tú mismo en el comentario, correcto? Creo que estas preguntas tendrían más éxito en https://serverfault.com/, pero está genial que hayas anotado cómo lo resolviste. Quizá estaría bien si escribes tú mismo la respuesta por si alguien la busca y no ve los comentarios? Un saludo!

Comment: Hola, si, gracias